# Объект внутри объекта?

Tags: php

Скажите пожалуйста, появилась востребованность в Soap, но вывод ответа сервера уже выполняется из объекта.
Поясню:
Есть объект core, создание и формерование страницы я делаю так: $core->display();
сам метод, в зависимост от параметров GET и POST формерует страничку и проделывает нужные операции.
Как мне внедрить туда соап?
Разве можно делать так:

```
class core {
public function display() {
$soap = new soap...
}
}
```

Так возможно?

Comment: class core extends soap { }

Comment: уже class core extends db { }
как сюда soap добавить?